# run command in bash and then exit without killing the command

Tags: bash, if-statement

I am attempting to run a couple commands in a bash script however it will hang up on my command waiting for it to complete (which it wont). this script is simply making sure its running.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps cax | grep python > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running."
else
  echo "Process is not running... Starting..."
  python likebot.py
  echo $(ps aux | grep python | grep -v color | awk {'print $2'})
fi
```

Once it gets to the python command it hangs up while the command is being executed. its not till i cntrl c before it gives the pid.  is there anyway i can have it run this bash script and exit the bash script once the commands were run (without waiting for them to complete).

Comment: Did you try the `&` operator already?

Comment: You should probably submit this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  The feedback will probably teach you a lot about shell programming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, if you want to execute a command and not wait for it, you can simply use `&` as the delimiter rather than `;` or a newline.  When doing so, the pid of that process is available to the shell in the special variable `!`.  If you want to wait for that process to complete, you can use `wait`.  If you do not wish to wait for it, then simply omit the `wait`.  In your case:

```
python likebot.py &  # Start command asynchronously
echo $!              # echo the pid of the most recent asynchronous process
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like likebot should be always running you might want to consider 'nohup' as well,   with a bare & the job is still a child of your login process and will die if that dies.